# Is it undefined behavior to compare function pointers reinterpret_cast to void(*)()?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, undefined-behavior

For example, can I make a `std::set<void(*)()>` and use `reinterpret_cast` to put arbitrary function pointers into it? I obviously wouldn’t be able to call them, but if I wanted to remember what functions I’ve seen, would `seen.count(reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(fn))` be defined behavior? For now I’m assuming the functions I care about aren’t overloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine. According to [expr.reinterpret.cast],

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type.

It also says that converting a function pointer to a different function pointer type and back will yield the original pointer type.

Comment: Does the Standard specify anything about whether all pointers to functions with one signature will compare unequal to pointers to functions with other signatures, or would it allow an implementation to represent e.g. an `int(*)(void)` as an index into a table of such functions, and a `int(*)(int)` as an index into a table of those, possibly using the same representation for the the fifth function of the first type as for the fifth function of the second?

Comment: @supercat It does not. Other than the requirement that converting a function pointer to a different function pointer type and back to the original type yields the original function pointer, "the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified"

Comment: Is that to say that my `std::set<void(*)()>` isn't correct? https://godbolt.org/z/5EocE7 shows `NaiveFunctionSet` and `FunctionSet`. It sounds like you are saying that `FunctionSet` is correct but `NaiveFunctionSet` is not.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Do you think `FunctionSet` in https://godbolt.org/z/5EocE7 is correct, using a `std::set<std::pair<const std::type_info*, void(*)()>>` to note which function pointers have been "seen"?